# How to Implement a KMP interface outside shared module in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KMP module called session-jwt-public with the following interface:

```kotlin
public interface JWTHandler {
  public fun decode(token: String): JwtDecodedResultWrapper
}

public data class JwtDecodedResultWrapper(
  val name: String,
  val email: String,
  val role: String,
  val sub: String
)
```

on my shared module I've added this module as commonMainImplementation(projects.sessionJwtPublic)

This is my binary configuration:

```kotlin
// gradle
kotlin {

  listOf(
    iosArm64(),
    iosSimulatorArm64(),
  ).forEach { iosTarget ->
    iosTarget.binaries.framework {
      baseName = "MyApp"
      isStatic = true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a classe like this in swift:

```swift
public final class JWTSwiftWrapped: JWTHandler {
    
    public func decode(token: String) -> JwtDecodedResultWrapper {
     /// decode here
    }
}
```

But I'm receiving:
*Cannot find type 'JWTHandler' in scope*

If I move the same interface to my shared module it works.

This is the build gradle of my session-jwt-public module:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("my.conversion.plugin")
}

dependencies {
    commonMainImplementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
    commonMainImplementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
}

android {
    namespace = "...."
}
```

Am I missing some configuration?

I've tried implement this interface in the shared module, it works, but I'd like to implement it in my dedicated module to follow the modules structure and also learn how to implement an interface from Kotlin in swift.